# lwip ip_addr - storage size of

Tags: c, networking, struct, typedef, lwip

I'm trying define "ip_addr" from lwip. That's my code:

```
#include "lwip/tcp.h"
#include "ip_addr.h"
...
struct ip_addr ip;
```

But when i'm trying to compile this, compiler gives me error:

```
error: storage size of 'ip' isn't known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ip_addr_t ip;
```

and your second #include line should it not be:

```
#include "lwip/ip_addr.h"
```